# Why are numpy and torch so much faster than R for matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, r, performance, numpy, torch

In Python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x0=np.random.rand(3000,3000)
>>> t=time.perf_counter(); y0=np.matmul(x0,x0); time.perf_counter()-t
0.8358144999947399

>>> import torch
>>> x=torch.rand(3000,3000)
>>> t=time.perf_counter(); y0=np.matmul(x,x); time.perf_counter()-t
0.4304323000833392
```

In R:

```
> a=matrix(runif(9000000), 3000, 3000)
> a1=a%*%a
> system.time({a1=a%*%a})
   user  system elapsed 
  16.53    0.04   16.57
```

Why is 20-fold difference with numpy and 40-fold difference with torch?

Comment: Is your python installation linked with some high performance matrix library? E.g. this operation takes only 1.3sec on my laptop that doesn't have parallelism enabled for matrix computation.

Comment: Standard installation from anaconda.

Comment: Yes. See https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/.

Comment: @F.Privé - which operation takes 1.3 sec on your laptop? 3000*3000 matrix multiplication in numpy?

Comment: `a1=a%*%a` in R.

Comment: Is `a` 3000*3000 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the code you provided.

Comment: For me it's: `user 0.594  system 0.030  relapsed 0.625`. Can you check which algebra library are you using

Comment: @PoGibas I use standard R under MS Windows 10. platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 arch: x86_64 os: mingw32  version.string: R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)

Comment: I'm afraid that problem comes because of the non-optimal interpreter which is hard to change in windows - https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-5-blas-and-alternative-r-interpreters.html#blas-and-alternative-r-interpreters